# What should be the shasum for The Mac Hera iso. Mine doesn't match the sum in the instructions

Tags: release-hera

What should be the shasum for The Mac Hera iso. Mine doesn't match the sum in the instructions. I get: 190bbf738db0f15daa9ee4095bb64c307950082819081a969f8edd51f1faab07

Comment: See the answer [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/22338/hash-next-to-sha265-doesnt-match-up)