# Hash next to "SHA265" doesn't match up

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install Elementary OS for the first time, and I'm having trouble. The installation guide says that the hash next to "SHA265" in Rufus should match with the hash shown in the guide, but they don't for me. I've also tried downloading the file through the magnet link, but it keeps doing the same thing. What's going on here? If it matters, the PC I'm trying to install it on is running windows 10.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The sha256sum in the Installation page is for `elementaryos-5.1-stable.20191202.iso`

But if you go ahead and download the new iso file, you'll get `elementaryos-5.1-stable.20200204.iso`, an updated one. My guess is the Installation page has not been updated yet with the new checksum.

For the new iso file, I get
`190bbf738db0f15daa9ee4095bb64c307950082819081a969f8edd51f1faab07`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on Linux (xubuntu). However, for me, the checksum matches the one in the website's repo [here](https://github.com/elementary/website/blob/master/docs/installation.md).

Answer (score 2):

I want to try it out. Both direct DL and Magnet link produce elementaryos-5.1-stable.20200204.iso
Webpage says (that same updated version) it should produce following SHA256 checksum:

```
cd66c32d53eab6f789b8e69e499305b7af0c9b3083ed54d50b111136d2795ea1
```

BUt I got 
`190bbf738db0f15daa9ee4095bb64c307950082819081a969f8edd51f1faab07` too,

I guess updated webpage is not fully updated as that checksum is reported for former 20191202 file

Answer (score 0):

I got this see if it matches, dude!
[image]